# Using plural and singular to refer to the same thing(s)

Tags: grammatical-number, sentence

I often have trouble expressing myself when I want to talk about some things (plural) holistically as a single thing.

For example, "differential equations are a form of expression...".

It doesn't seem right to say that somethings (plural) are a something (singular), but I would like to say something like this if it can be done at all correctly.

Comment: There's no rule in English grammar that disallows different grammatical number on either side of the verb *"to be"* (which usually should agree with the expression on its left). Consider this [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are+a+form+of%2C+is+a+form+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Care%20a%20form%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20a%20form%20of%3B%2Cc0) for *"is/are a form of"*.

Comment: rmp251 Yes, you can.

Comment: "It doesn't seem right" is a very weak reason. This is perfectly grammatical, and perfectly common. And not just in English, but in a great many languages. You will have to clarify why you think it is not acceptable. Failing that, just use it.

Comment: Could you just refer to them both singularly, as in:

"A differential equation is an expression which..."

Would that fit your purpose?

Comment: Widgets are a type of placeholder.

Comment: 'Two's company, three's a crowd' mixes singular/plural and noncount/count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is common and acceptable to have a plural noun relating with/to a singular one.

> - Proteolytic *enzymes* *are* *a* special class of hydrolyases called peptidases.
> - The catalytic chemistry of enzymes is the key to designing potent inhibitors and makes *them* *a* special *class* of drug target.
> - Filoviruses are classified as biosafety level 4 by the CDC...
> - *Eutherians*, also known as placental mammals, *are a* large portion of the mammalian class.
> - As one might expect, the *letters* *have been* *an* invaluable *resource* for art historians and biographers.

It is common in formal English, and more so in informal English.

Comment: The examples are helpful.