# Subject-verb agreement question

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, singular-subject-and-verb

Quick question. Does the sentence below seem grammatically correct?

"Employees are a great resource for connecting you to the right product."

My gut is telling me that even though "employees" is plural, in this instance it is a singular resource. Does that make sense? Thank you!

Comment: Coming right after a plural noun, _are_ is required. And your gut is wrong; _resource_ is indeed singular, but _employees_ is a plural noun and it's the subject. In any event, employees can only function resourcefully as a group of individuals.

Comment: Are you actually asking about whether the object ("a great resource") needs to "agree" with the subject/verb? See https://english.stackexchange.com/q/188894/191178

Comment: I guess that's where I'm unsure. Because employees can be seen as a group (singular), would that make it a single resource? Or is this sentence just plain wrong, and do I need to say "Employees are great resources"? Or I could just rewrite it. Subject-verb agreement is one area where I struggle a bit when it comes to things like that. I also looked at the link provided and I'm still not sure if this particular instance works.

Comment: It must be a plural verb. "Employees" cannot be interpreted as a collective noun, so the singular override is not possible. Your original example is thus correct. Note that in almost all cases, the number of the subject NP determines the number of the predicand (verb).

Comment: Ohh, I understand. I guess the way I asked the question was confusing. Basically all I meant to ask was if the sentence was grammatically correct. I know that "Employees is a great resource" would be grammatically incorrect. I suppose what I was doing was trying to justify in my head how the sentence would work, but in the process made it more confusing? Either way, as long as the sentence I used above is grammatically proper, that's what's important.

Comment: Also to clarify, I wanted to be sure I could say "Employees are a great resource" instead of saying "Employees are great resources," since the latter doesn't sound right to me. Again, sorry for the confusion of how I framed this post.